# Failed to minify the code from this file (node_modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to build my React project using npm run build, when I run this command in the console I get the following error:

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
    ./node_modules/react-notification-alert/index.js:4
```

I checked the index.js file but at line 4 there is the class declaration of the notifications.

The generate log file contains the following:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prebuild: frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\sande\Desktop\Project-5-6\frontend\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\sande\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\sande\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\sande\Desktop\Project-5-6\frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\sande\Desktop\Project-5-6\frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.4.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
```

When I run "npm start" to view the project in my browser everything works fine. I already tried updating npm, react and react-notification-alert. All this resulted in the same error.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Simply the library is published not production ready.

You'll have to fork it and remove the line number 4:

```
import './animate.css';
```

not only it implies special webpack config, but the file is not event present in the library at all, real fun!

Actually it would easier just copy the code straight into your project and forget